# How to convert a test tube assay to microplate assay?

Tags: biochemistry, lab-techniques

I am trying to measure Ascorbic acid levels in tissue using Omaye et al protocol (Methods in Enzymology, Volume 62, 1979, Pages 3-11). This method is based on reduction of ferric chloride and subsequent detection by 2, 2'-dipyridyl. However, this assay is a test tube based assay. I want to convert this protocol into a plate based assay, however, I could not find any already published protocol for this. Is it possible to do it?